# Julia output from named pipe to a submission log

Tags: bash, redirect, julia, named-pipes

I am trying the following out to create an instance of Julia within a bash script, run a julia script and then redirect all the output to submission.log:

```
mkfifo pipe
sleep 1000000 > pipe &
julia < pipe &

{
    echo "include(\"test.jl\")" > pipe
    wait
} &> submission.log
```

however, output goes to the console and submission.log is empty. what is a good fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redirect stdout and stderr of Julia process:

```
julia <pipe >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt &
```

Comment: Thanks Bogumit. will start another thread for follow up question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510815/named-pipe-does-not-wait-until-completion-in-bash