# Named pipe does not wait until completion in bash

Tags: bash, redirect, julia, named-pipes

In the following test.jl creates an output.txt and generates some console output. console output is very well handled. but control returns immediately after echo even before output.txt is created completely. placing a wait in between echo and mv causes an indefinite wait. Should a carriage return be passed to the pipe without killing the pipe yet?

```
mkfifo pipe
sleep 1000000 > pipe &
julia <pipe >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt &

echo "include(\"test.jl\")" > pipe
mv output.txt temp/
echo "include(\"test2.jl\")" > pipe
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking `julia` to create the file in the background, and then immediately try to move it. This is a race condition. You need to find a way to wait for it. Ways include running one `julia` instance for each so that you can wait for the process to exit, have the program log something to stdout.txt that you can periodically check for, guess that it'll take less than 60 seconds and sleep for that long, or have `test.jl` itself move the file when it's done.

Comment: Think about what the effects would be if behavior was different than this and a program had to wait for what it wrote to be completely processed downstream before it could regain control from the write operation -- if you were running `find` piped into `xargs rm`, it couldn't go on and find a second file until the first one were completely finished being deleted. You'd need to come up with a completely new set of flow-control constructs to communicate when such processing is complete -- and what value would you get in return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that `test.jl` and `test2.jl` both write to `output.txt` so you have to move the file to another directory before running `test2.jl` or `test2.jl` expects `output.txt` in `temp/` directory and you have to move it there before `text2.jl` runs.

If yes then the following code should solve the problem:

```
mkfifo pipe
sleep 1000000 > pipe &
julia <pipe >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt &

echo "include(\"test.jl\")" > pipe
echo "mv(\"output.txt\", \"temp/\")" > pipe
echo "include(\"test2.jl\")" > pipe
```

In this way Julia runs `mv` command and you make sure that it is executed after `test.jl` but before `test2.jl`.

But actually we are getting to a point where it would be better to write a Julia script named e.g. `script.jl`:

```
include("test.jl")
mv("output.txt", "temp/")
include("test2.jl")
```

and run it using `julia script.jl`.

Comment: Keeping the OP's `sleep` hack is unfortunate. Consider replacing it with (*after* the `julia` invocation) `exec 3>pipe`, and then do your `echo`s with `>&3` on the output end; that way there's just one file descriptor used for the pipe's input end that's held open rather than having the number of FDs on it vary over time.

Comment: Is there a better way to keep a named pipe open so that Julia does not receive EOF after the first `echo`? We are assuming an interactive session - not a script - with Julia running in the background.

Comment: The approach I suggested in my above comment does just that. `exec 3>pipe` is perfectly valid in an interactive session.

Comment: Thanks. I was writing in parallel.

Comment: (When you *do* want to close the pipe, by the way, you can do that with `exec 3>&-`).

Comment: does julia exit when pipe is closed?