# use timeout with exec in bash

Tags: bash, pipe

How can I kill matlab after it is loaded and then a timeout occurs?

```
rm -rf pipe
mkfifo pipe

time matlab -nosplash -nodesktop <pipe 2>&1 | tee sub.log > /dev/null &
pid=$!
exec 3> pipe
sleep 25s
echo "MyMatlab1('1','2');quit" >&3
####timeout 600 exec 3>&-    #alternative?
```

Reference:
[Named pipe does not wait until completion in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510815/named-pipe-does-not-wait-until-completion-in-bash)

Comment: Do you need to use mathlab's quit command, or would an OS signal be alright? If so, use the `timeout` utility, e.g. `timeout 25s mathlab <<<"MyMatlab1('1','2')"`

Comment: Matlab should already be loaded. An OS solution is needed. Matlab's quit is included in case MyMatlab1() exits within the timeout