# Named pipe crashes in bash

Tags: bash, pipe

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510815/named-pipe-does-not-wait-until-completion-in-bash) proposes a solution to the premature closing of a pipe.

Executing the code

```
mkfifo pipe
julia <pipe >log.txt 2>err.txt &
exec 3>pipe
echo "1+2" >&3
echo "X" >&3
echo "exit()" >&3 

cat log.txt
cat err.txt
```

in different environments:

- Windows/Git Bash: *echo "1+2" >&3* crashes
- Linux/Konsole+bash: $ echo "1+2" >&3 crashes with
  *Warning: Program '/bin/bash' crashed.*
- Linux/Xterm+bash: working

Bash experts?

Comment: git-bash? So you're on Windows? Not sure if it supports unix-style named pipes.

Comment: pls see my update.